# RecycleView repeat action on one recycleview card on other

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am developing one quiz android application in which questions and their respective options and answer will be fetched from server and added to recycle view.
I have done coding of same and it is working except one problem that when i choose any option i turn its background green if it is right or i turn it to red if it is wrong but when i do same for any question same action is been transformed on other questions option in recycle view.

[As i click on Option A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TA98.png)

[6th question from previous solved question have option A automatically selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex3p6.png)

I am posting my Adapter and Fragment code for same.

Adapter code:-

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    Log.e("I : ", "Creating " );
    switch (viewType) {

        case QUESTION:
            View viewQuestion = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_card, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new QuestionFeed(viewQuestion);
            break;
        case LOADING:
            View viewLoading = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_progress, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new LoadingVH(viewLoading);
            break;


    }
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final PostRead result = postResults.get(position);
    String catname = null;
    try {
        catname = dataBaseHelper.getCatName(result.getCat());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("Position: ", "" + position);
    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {


        case QUESTION:
            final QuestionFeed textFeed = (QuestionFeed) holder;
            textFeed.question.setText(result.getQuestion());
            textFeed.optionA.setText(result.getA());
            textFeed.optionB.setText(result.getB());
            textFeed.optionC.setText(result.getC());
            textFeed.optionD.setText(result.getD());
            textFeed.answerView.setText(catname);
            textFeed.time.setText("" + TimeAgo.getTimeAgo((10000000000000L - result.getTimestamp())));

            textFeed.optionA_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    if (result.getAnswer().equals("a")) {
                        Log.e("AAAAnswer- ", result.getAnswer());
                        textFeed.optionA_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.right_answer));

                    } else {
                        Log.e("Answer- ", result.getAnswer());
                        textFeed.optionA_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.wrong_answer));
                        if (result.getAnswer().equals("b")) {
                            textFeed.optionB_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.right_answer));

                        } else if (result.getAnswer().equals("c")) {
                            textFeed.optionC_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.right_answer));

                        } else if (result.getAnswer().equals("d")) {
                            textFeed.optionD_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.right_answer));
                        }
                    }
                    if (textFeed.descView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                        textFeed.descView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
            textFeed.optionB_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (result.getAnswer().equals("b")) {
                        Log.e("BBBAnswer- ", result.getAnswer());
                        textFeed.optionB_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.right_answer));
                    } else {
                        textFeed.optionB_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.wrong_answer));
                        if (result.getAnswer().equals("a")) {
                            textFeed.optionA_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.right_answer));

                        } else if (result.getAnswer().equals("c")) {
                            textFeed.optionC_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.right_answer));

                        } else if (result.getAnswer().equals("d")) {
                            textFeed.optionD_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.right_answer));

                        }
                    }
                    if (textFeed.descView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                        textFeed.descView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
            textFeed.optionC_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (result.getAnswer().equals("c")) {
                        Log.e("CCCAnswer- ", result.getAnswer());
                        textFeed.optionC_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.right_answer));
                    } else {
                        textFeed.optionC_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.wrong_answer));
                        if (result.getAnswer().equals("b")) {
                            textFeed.optionB_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.right_answer));

                        } else if (result.getAnswer().equals("a")) {
                            textFeed.optionA_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.right_answer));

                        } else if (result.getAnswer().equals("d")) {
                            textFeed.optionD_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.right_answer));

                        }
                    }
                    if (textFeed.descView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                        textFeed.descView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
            textFeed.optionD_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (result.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
                        Log.e("DDDAnswer- ", result.getAnswer());
                        textFeed.optionD_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.right_answer));
                    } else {
                        Log.e("DDDAnswer- ", result.getAnswer());
                        textFeed.optionD_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.wrong_answer));
                        if (result.getAnswer().equals("b")) {
                            textFeed.optionB_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.right_answer));

                        } else if (result.getAnswer().equals("c")) {
                            textFeed.optionC_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.right_answer));

                        } else if (result.getAnswer().equals("a")) {
                            textFeed.optionA_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.right_answer));

                        }
                    }
                    if (textFeed.descView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                        textFeed.descView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
            break;
    }
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return postResults == null ? 0 : postResults.size();
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return QUESTION;
}
public void add(PostRead r) {
    postResults.add(r);
    notifyItemInserted(postResults.size() - 1);
}
public void addAll(List<PostRead> moveResults) {
    for (PostRead result : moveResults) {
        add(result);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public void remove(PostRead r) {
    int position = postResults.indexOf(r);
    if (position > -1) {
        postResults.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}
public void clear() {
    isLoadingAdded = false;
    while (getItemCount() > 0) {
        remove(getItem(0));
    }
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return getItemCount() == 0;
}
public void addLoadingFooter() {
    isLoadingAdded = true;
    add(new PostRead());
}
public void removeLoadingFooter() {
    isLoadingAdded = false;
    int position = postResults.size() - 1;
    PostRead result = getItem(position);
    if (result != null) {
        postResults.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}
public PostRead getItem(int position) {
    return postResults.get(position);
}


protected class QuestionFeed extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView back, share;
    private MyTextView question;
    private MyTextView optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD, answerView, time;
    private LinearLayout optionA_layout, optionB_layout, optionC_layout, optionD_layout, errorLayout, descView;
    private ProgressBar mProgress;
    private Button btnRetry;
    private TextView txtError;
    private RelativeLayout mainLayout, backButton;

    public QuestionFeed(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        back = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.backView);
        back = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.share);
        question = (MyTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.question);
        optionA = (MyTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionA);
        optionB = (MyTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionB);
        optionC = (MyTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionC);
        optionD = (MyTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionD);
        answerView = (MyTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject);
        time = (MyTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        optionA_layout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionbuttonA);
        optionB_layout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionbuttonB);
        optionC_layout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionbuttonC);
        optionD_layout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionbuttonD);
        mProgress = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_progress);
        mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.content_sign_up);
        backButton = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        descView = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        errorLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.error_layout);
        btnRetry = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.error_btn_retry);
        txtError = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.error_txt_cause);


    }
}
```

Fragment Code

```
private void loadFirstPage() {

    hideErrorView();

    Query query = postRef.orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(firstTime).limitToFirst(14);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            final List<PostRead> allPosts = new ArrayList<>();
            childCount = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // TODO: handle the post
                Log.e("Online ", "" + firstTime);
                PostRead catItems = postSnapshot.getValue(PostRead.class);
                catItems.setPostkey(postSnapshot.getKey());
                allPosts.add(catItems);
                childCount--;
                if (childCount == 0) {
                    firstStart = 0;
                    dataBaseHelper.updatePosts(allPosts);
                    hideErrorView();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    adapter.addAll(allPosts);
                    isLoading = false;
                    if (allPosts.size() == 0) {
                        isLastPage = true;
                    } else adapter.addLoadingFooter();
                }
                firstTime = catItems.getTimestamp();


            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `Views` are recycled by `RecyclerView` and you are setting background color to different color manually.
The solution is to set default color for background of your `textFeed` in `BindViewHolder` as:

```
textFeed.optionA_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.default_color));
textFeed.optionB_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.default_color));
textFeed.optionC_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.default_color));
textFeed.optionD_layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.default_color));
```

Comment: Thanks solution worked,Actually,i thought i have set default color in xml and i update color in onClickListner so it will not change color for other element but i was wrong, thanks again.